# Trouble loading JW Player consistently on KiK

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6, appjs, kik

I'm having trouble getting JW Player (JW Platform) videos to load on KiK (and just mobile web, for that matter). Appears to work 100% of the time on desktop, but once inside the KiK app or even just in Safari and/or Chrome mobile web the videos will some time not load. 
In the iOS console log for Safari, I receive this error pointing to the kik.js include:

```
[Log] Error handling "jwplayerPlaylistLoaded" event listener [0]: TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'ja.parentNode') function (a) {u.playlist=a.playlist;G=e;c();}  (kik.js, line 12)
Object
playlist: Array[1]
type: "jwplayerPlaylistLoaded"
version: "6.9.4867"
__proto__: Object
```

Here is a link for review: http://vibetenders.fullbottle.tv/index-breaking.php
One thing to note, I'm using JW Platform. And I'm using their javascript implementation method instead of their iframe implementation method since I need to use the player's event listeners for tracking.

I have placed one of the video scripts directly in the source code so that it is triggered as the kik home loads, which has definitely seemed to help reduce the errors, but I still do get them. When there is no error like the example above, then the video page loads and plays nicely.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it has less to do with kik and more to do with your use of JW + App.js

From what I can tell an element being used by JW is being removed from the DOM and thus is causing the exception (since it has no parent anymore).

Are initializing JW in the App.js controller for the video page?

Comment: Yes, the JW is being initialized on when clicking to load the video page. I'm using a document.createElement('script') in order to start the jw platform script which essentially looks like this: http://content.jwplatform.com/players/qgmTVRux-tdrwAxZs.js (first set of random characters is the jw platform video id, and the second set after the hyphen is the jw platform player id). Any suggestions on what I might try for a fix? Thanks for the help!

Comment: An update here: using the standard html5 video tag appears to be the best method. Doing so removes all the complexity that comes with the JW Platform .js file, which might be causing a conflict with App.js as noted by "jairajs89". I'm still able to reference the JW-hosted video files that are uploaded to the platform, but I just make reference to the .mp4 (for example) instead of the video id and  player id that are part of the jw platform .js include.